# 128 bit (a * b) / c in Rust with phantom overflow protection

Tags: rust, solidity, integer-overflow

Let a, b, and c be 128 bit numbers. A phantom overflow happens when the intermediary value `a * b` overflows 128 bits. However the final product after division `numerator / c` fits inside 128 bits.

For 64 bit and smaller numbers, one can cast to 128 bits or use the [muldiv crate](https://docs.rs/muldiv/1.0.0/muldiv/). What is the best way to do this for 128 bit numbers? Issue is that:

- Rust does not have native types larger than 128 bits
- muldiv crate does not have 128 bit support

Reference- [muldiv in solidity by Remco Bloemen](https://xn--2-umb.com/21/muldiv/index.html)

Comment: (6*2)/3 = 4          (6/3)*2 = 4... Am I understanding the question wrong? To prevent the overflow just divide first and then multiply

Comment: This way `u64::pow(2, 48) * (u64::pow(2, 48) / u64::MAX)`will give 0 in place of `2^32`.

Comment: A "quick & dirty" way would be to use a bigint (such as [this one](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/latest/num_bigint/struct.BigInt.html)), to do the multiplication and division, and then convert back to `u128` / `i128`. This is likely not very performant, but it should always work, and lets you detect if the result after the division actually fits in 128 bits or not.

Comment: If you know values like c (constant) there could be faster ways to calculate it.

Comment: Note: This overflow behaviour and the difficulty of this process is the reason why bigint libraries store their digits in the second largest integral data type defined by the language. That way they can implement multiplication without resorting to extreme means

Answer (score 2):

Unless there exists simpler/easier method (of which I am unaware), this is NOT as trivial as it looks. It took longer than expected to make, but I came up with the following code. I have not tested it well, I cannot guarantee it is accurate, and it almost certainly isn't optimal. However, it seemed to work with a few test cases. Use at your own risk ‍♂️:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b2d0358e565ede89c8f4acd07e6235c6)

```rust
// Inspired by: https://medium.com/wicketh/mathemagic-512-bit-division-in-solidity-afa55870a65

/// Returns the least significant 64 bits of a
fn lo128(a: u128) -> u128 {
    a & ((1<<64)-1)
}

/// Returns the most significant 64 bits of a
fn hi128(a: u128) -> u128 {
    a >> 64
}

/// Returns 2^128 - a (two's complement)
fn neg128(a: u128) -> u128 {
    (!a).wrapping_add(1)
}

/// Returns 2^128 / a
fn div128(a: u128) -> u128 {
    (neg128(a)/a).wrapping_add(1)
}

/// Returns 2^128 % a
fn mod128(a: u128) -> u128 {
    neg128(a) % a
}

/// Returns a+b (wrapping)
fn add256(a0: u128, a1: u128, b0: u128, b1: u128) -> (u128, u128) {
    let (r0, overflow) = a0.overflowing_add(b0);
    let r1 = a1.wrapping_add(b1).wrapping_add(overflow as u128);
    (r0, r1)
}

/// Returns a*b (in 256 bits)
fn mul128(a: u128, b: u128) -> (u128, u128) {
    // Split a and b into hi and lo 64-bit parts
    // a*b = (a1<<64 + a0)*(b1<<64 + b0)
    // = (a1*b1)<<128 + (a1*b0 + b1*a0)<<64 + a0*b0
    let (a0, a1) = (lo128(a), hi128(a));
    let (b0, b1) = (lo128(b), hi128(b));
    let (x, y) = (a1*b0, b1*a0);
    
    let (r0, r1) = (a0*b0, a1*b1);
    let (r0, r1) = add256(r0, r1, lo128(x)<<64, hi128(x));
    let (r0, r1) = add256(r0, r1, lo128(y)<<64, hi128(y));
    (r0, r1)
}

/// Returns a/b
fn div256_128(mut a0: u128, mut a1: u128, b: u128) -> (u128, u128) {
    if b == 1 {
        return (a0, a1);
    }
    // Calculate a/b
    // = (a0<<128 + a1)/b
    //   let (q, r) = (div128(b), mod128(b));
    // = (a1*(q*b + r)) + a0)/b
    // = (a1*q*b + a1*r + a0)/b
    // = (a1*r + a0)/b + a1*q
    let (q, r) = (div128(b), mod128(b));
    
    // x = current result
    // a = next number
    // t = temp
    let (mut x0, mut x1) = (0, 0);
    while a1 != 0 {
        // x += a1*q
        let (t0, t1) = mul128(a1, q);
        let (new_x0, new_x1) = add256(x0, x1, t0, t1);
        x0 = new_x0;
        x1 = new_x1;
        // a = a1*r + a0
        let (t0, t1) = mul128(a1, r);
        let (new_a0, new_a1) = add256(t0, t1, a0, 0);
        a0 = new_a0;
        a1 = new_a1;
    }
    
    add256(x0, x1, a0/b, 0)
}

/// Returns a*b/c (wrapping to 128 bits)
fn muldiv128(a: u128, b: u128, c: u128) -> u128 {
    let (t0, t1) = mul128(a, b);
    div256_128(t0, t1, c).0
}

fn main() {
    let a = 54994939174662544931549714329375118023;
    let b = 100391518367866121278432408876359705009;
    let c = 183619791236921872854293928964252165930;
    let result = muldiv128(a, b, c);
    let expected = 30067703536211509756706998560804057558;
    println!("{}", result == expected); // true
}
```

Alternatively, if you know that the numbers divide evenly, you can simply do `(a/gcd(a, c)) * (b/gcd(b, c)) * gcd(a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying two 128 bit numbers result in 256 bits of output. There may be an assembly instruction that lets you get at those bits.

Alternatively you can chop each 128 bit integer into an upper 64-bit half and a lower 64-bit half. Multiplying those halves results in a maximum of 128 bits of output and thus can be done in an 128-bit integer.

```
(a_up*2^64 + a_lo) * (b_up*2^64 + b_lo) = a_up*b_up*2^128 + a_up*b_lo*2^64 + a_lo*b_up*2^64 + a_lo*b_lo
```

Therefore the upper 128 bits are `a_up*b_up*2^128 + (a_up*b_lo*2^64 + a_lo*b_up*2^64)_up` and the lower 128 bits are `(a_up*b_lo*2^64 + a_lo*b_up*2^64 + a_lo*b_lo)_lo`.

Then you only need to divide this 256 bit result by c...

Comment: I think you need to detect (before the overflow happens) and propagate the carry from lower part to upper part. Can you give the detail the 256 bit division (on two halves of 128 bits each)?

Comment: @prog-fh, we have an expression for the full 256-bit result, so the two 128-bit halves are hi and lo of that. Each part simplifies a little further because both `(a_up*b_up*2^128)_lo` and `(a_lo*b_lo)_hi` are zero.

Comment: @prog-fh, for the division I am not sure what an efficient way would be, but it seems not too hard to implement some form of long division. I am sure there is a literature if that is not good enough.